# Existe diferença entre ser explícito com o tipo do objeto que está sendo criado ou usar apenas new()?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, desempenho, instanciar-objeto

Existe diferença entre

```
var list = new List<string>();
```

e

```
List<string> list = new();
```

Eu sei que usar `var` ou o tipo explicitamente dá na mesma, mas não sei se essa nova forma é igual.

Se for igual por que criaram mais uma forma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dá na mesma. É só mais uma forma de expressar mesmo, não muda nada como é compilado ou como vai desempenhar na execução, eles geram exatamente o mesmo código, é quase como se fosse outra inferência, mas neste caso não é porque o tipo está sendo explicitado na declaração da variável.

Uma das vantagens é que pode ser usado em todos os lugares, não só em variáveis locais. Pode por exemplo usar em campos. Agora pode ter uma sintaxe mais curta e sem redundância onde antes não era possível descobrir inequivocamente qual era o tipo.

Mais ainda, pode ser usado em qualquer lugar onde o tipo já foi explicitado antes, por exemplo:

```
List<Carro> list = new() { new(), new() };
```

Os dois objetos criados e colocados na lista serão `Carro`s. É exatamente o mesmo que escrever:

```
List<Carro> list = new List<Carro>() { new Carro(), new Carro() };
```

Em alguns casos não tem como usar, mas são casos que o `var` não fica muito bom, perde informação relevante para contextualizar na leitura, o compilador se vira bem, o programador não:

```
var s = GetListCarro();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/TargetType.cs).

O compilador pode rodar um pouco mais rápido usando `new()` do que com `var`, mas nada muito significativo.

O nome disso é *target type*.